# Question related to number theory and partition of sets.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, prime-numbers

Q. Consider the set $\{5,6,7,8,9\}$. For any partition $\{A,B\}$ of $E$, with both $A$ and $B$ non-empty, consider the number obtained by adding the product of elements of $A$ to the product of elements of $B$. Let $N$ be the largest prime number among these numbers. Find the sum of the digits of $N$.

So I was actually able to solve this problem, however my method seems to be very inefficient. I wonder if there is a faster solution to this, like a pattern I may be missing.

My solution:
WLOG, let set $A$ contain only odd elements. Then there are $7$ possible set $A$s. $\{5\}$, $\{7\}$, $\{9\}$, $\{5,7\}$, $\{7,9\}$, $\{5,9\}$, $\{5,7,9\}$.
Then corresponding set $B$s contain the remaining elements.

Now product of elements of A + product of elements of B ≡ $\pm 1 \mod 6$(since it is a prime). This narrows the overall possibilites down to $3$.

1. $SET A = \{5\} \\  SET B = \{6,7,8,9\} \\ Possible \ N=3029 $
2. $SET A = \{7\} \\  SET B = \{5,6,8,9\} \\ Possible \ N=2167$
3. $SET A = \{5,7\} \\  SET B = \{6,8,9\} \\ Possible \ N=467$

So the number $N$ is $467$.
Again, any other more efficient way to do this?

Comment: What you've done seems the most efficient path to an answer. I can't see an "easier" or more analytical way to go about it.

Comment: @EricSnyder I found a solution on the internet which instantly concluded that 6,8,9 should be in a single set. How does one reach that conclusion?

Comment: I... don't know how they came to an "instant" conclusion. Alas.